# Integrating AIR Native Extension with FLA Project

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I am trying to use the IOS in-app native extension, which is found at (http://code.google.com/p/in-app-purchase-air-ios/), and I have linked the SWC with my flash project...

The problem I am having is that all of the usage code talks about integrating with a Flex project rather then an FLA - does anyone know if it is possible to port this extension for use with a flash project?

Regards,

Dave.

Comment: Flash Builder needs an update to support Native Extensions; most likely Flash Pro does too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rename the .ane to a SWC: ADT will find the .ane if you add a link to a directory containing .ane files. You can add the .swc to your project for code completion if you have one. Check the last part of my command (I used Flash Professional):

```
SDK/bin/adt -package -target ipa-test-interpreter -storetype pkcs12 -provisioning-profile dev.mobileprovision -keystore Apple_dev_cert_export.p12 gyro.ipa gyro-app.xml gyro.swf -extdir exDir
```

I made a video for Flash Professional combining the process of overlaying the AIR3 SDK, creating a project using gyroscope native extension and compiling with ADT, installing the app on my iPad using Xcode. Hope this helps somebody!

http://www.sworl.be/air-native-extensions-in-flash/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got a native extension (ANE) to work using the Flash IDE.  You need to rename the .ane file to a .swc file.

This video should help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Axg6E001a7I

EDIT:

This assumes that you have overlayed the Air 3.0 SDK on Flash, and installed the ADT command-line tool.  As of now, you can only package apps that use native extensions with ADT.

More info on overlaying the Air 3.0 SDK: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/908/cpsid_90810.html